# Java in bash at university fails with NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, bash, noclassdeffounderror, java-6

I know there are many posts concerning NoClassDefFoundError, they all seem to be talking about jar files. While I'm comfortable with java in eclipse, I'm pretty lost as to why the simplest thing I can come up with is not functioning, unless they broke something on the university side of this.

```
public class hello {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
            System.out.println ("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

This is the entire hello.java program which throws this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hello/java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hello.java
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
Could not find the main class: hello.java.  Program will exit.
```

$CLASSPATH=./:/usr/java/latest/lib:/home/41/myusername/bin

```
java -verbose hello.class
```

gives:

```
[Opened /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_10/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Object from /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_10/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.io.Serializable from /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_10/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Comparable from /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_10/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.CharSequence from /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_10/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.String from /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_10/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.reflect.GenericDeclaration from /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_10/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.reflect.Type from /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_10/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement from /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_10/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Class from /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_10/jre/lib/rt.jar]
...
[Loaded sun.misc.AtomicLong from /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_10/jre/lib/rt.jar]
...
```

with the exception again.

```
java -version
```

gives:

```
java version "1.6.0_10-rc2"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_10-rc2-b32)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 11.0-b15, mixed mode)
```

Comment: @Joachim how did you do the nice scrolling box? is there a way I can view the markup used to edit my post? I want to learn how to do it also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it you did you actually compile the class first?:

```
javac hello.java
java hello
```

Comment: I thought java wasn't a compiled language.

Comment: @Maslow: of course it is a compiled language. It's compiled to byte code.

Comment: It sure is - but if you want to pretend it isn't you could take a look at groovy.

Answer (score 9):

First, compile your `.java` file using the [`javac`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) `hello.java` to produce a `hello.class` file. Then, execute the class using the command [`java`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) `hello` - you don't include the `.class` extension when using the `java` command.

Also, I would like to point out that it is convention that class names begin with a capital letter - `hello` should be `Hello`.

Comment: yeah I'm used to the capital letters for class in C#, and I tried renaming it to a capital letter in case that was the problem.

Comment: java hello doesn't work, until it's compiled apparently I missed the compile step and didn't know the difference between .java and .class

Answer (score 2):

```
java -verbose hello.class
```

... means "hey, Java, run the main() method in the class 'hello.class'.

Java can't find a class named "hello.class". Your class is called "hello".

```
java -verbose hello
```

Since '.' is in your classpath, Java will find the 'hello' class in './hello.class'.

Extra tip: it's conventional in Java to start classes with a capital letter.

```
public class Hello {
```

This helps to distinguish between class references and variable references in the rest of your code.

```
Dessert dessert= new Dessert("tiramisu")
```

Comment: Is Desert a subclass of Dessert? ;-)

Comment: @slim - java hello doesn't work, until it's compiled apparently I missed the compile step and didn't know the difference between .java and .class

Answer (score 1):

```
java -verbose hello
```